# Animation repeats when another animation is defined in hover

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I want to make an animation when page loads. Animation that I defined in `#logo` repeats if one more animations is defined in `#logo:hover` and I move the mouse from the logo. How to fix it?

[Demo](https://codepen.io/volkovik/pen/oNxVRdm)

```css
@keyframes pulse_logo {
    5% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    14% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    18% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes popout {
    from {
        transform: scale(0)
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1)
    }
}

#logo {
    transition: 0.3s;
    animation: popout 1s ease;
}

#logo:hover {
    filter: invert(1);
    animation-name: pulse_logo;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: That's working by design, since you're changing the `animation` property. The "fix" to it would involve getting JavaScript to change stuff once it's loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put effects inside of div with different id name.

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

@keyframes pulse_logo {
    5% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    14% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    18% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes popout {
    from {
        transform: scale(0)
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1)
    }
}

#logo {
    font-size: 80px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    animation: popout 1s ease;
}

#logoh:hover {
    filter: invert(1);
    animation-name: pulse_logo;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <p id="logoh">Text
    <p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do, I think, is to apply the second animation to an inner element, for example a span, like so:

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
@keyframes pulse_logo {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes popout {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

#logo {
  animation: popout 1s ease;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#logo span:hover {
  filter: invert(1);
  animation: pulse_logo 500ms ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<p id="logo"><span>Text</span><p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep both animations and only adjust `animation-play-state`

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}


#logo {
    font-size: 80px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    animation: 
      popout 1s ease,
      pulse_logo 4s infinite paused;
}

#logo:hover {
    filter: invert(1);
    animation-play-state:running;
}

@keyframes pulse_logo {
    5% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    14% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    18% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes popout {
    from {
        transform: scale(0)
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1)
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="logo">Text<p>
```

Or only change the one you need:

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

#logo {
    font-size: 80px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    animation: 
      popout 1s ease,
      random_name 4s infinite; /* a random name here that you change on hover */
}

#logo:hover {
    filter: invert(1);
    animation: 
      popout 1s ease,
      pulse_logo 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse_logo {
    5% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    14% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    18% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes popout {
    from {
        transform: scale(0)
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1)
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="logo">Text<p>
```

Comment: Second animation is broken because this one must restart but this just paused when I move the mouse from the logo and continue when I hover the logo.

Comment: @volkovik that's why I provided two methods. One will restart the animation and the other will pause and continue, Feel free to use the one you want